# wierd arp issue with 2 interafces sharing same subnet

Tags: linux, subnet, arp

I have two linux machines connected through a switch.

bothe machines run linux RHEL 7.3 kernel 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64

one of the machines is connected with both ports to the switch and the other with one port.

**both ports share same subnet**.

```
ifconfig machine 1
ens3f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 6.6.6.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 6.6.6.255
        ether 34:9a:17:aa:28:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

ifconfig machine 2

ens1f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 6.6.6.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 6.6.6.255
    ether 34:9a:17:65:55:5d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

ens3f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 6.6.6.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 6.6.6.255
    ether 34:9a:17:aa:26:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

i flushed the arp tables using

```
ip -s neigh flush
```

then i run a tcp server on machine 1 (with one port), and a tcp client that binds to a specific device (device ens3f1 with ip 6.6.6.12) on machine 2.  i see this in the arp table of the server (machine1)

```
ip neigh show
6.6.6.12 dev ens3f1 lladdr 34:9a:17:65:55:5d REACHABLE
10.224.12.254 dev eno1 lladdr 00:00:5e:00:01:01 REACHABLE
6.6.6.11 dev ens3f1  FAILED
```

as you can see in the arp table i see a connection between ip 6.6.6.12 and mac 34:9a:17:65:55:5d but in the ifconfig you see this data is not correct.
after running agian the clinet with bind to the other port (6.6.6.11) i see this arp table

```
6.6.6.12 dev ens3f1 lladdr 34:9a:17:65:55:5d REACHABLE
10.224.12.254 dev eno1 lladdr 00:00:5e:00:01:01 REACHABLE
6.6.6.11 dev ens3f1 lladdr 34:9a:17:65:55:5d REACHABLE
```

here you can see both ip's has the same mac!!
doe's anyone know how to solve this issue?
this is the tcpdump in the two machines

```
tcpdump: listening on ens1f1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size    65535 bytes
17:36:39.309925 34:9a:17:aa:28:1b (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has ***** (Broadcast) tell 6.6.6.2, length 46
17:36:39.309931 34:9a:17:65:55:5d (oui Unknown) > 34:9a:17:aa:28:1b (oui Unknown), ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply ****** is-at 34:9a:17:65:65:5d (oui Unknown), length 28

tcpdump -i ens3f1 -e -vv
tcpdump: listening on ens3f1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:36:39.309941 34:9a:17:aa:28:1b (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has r-aa-nitro01.rdmz.labs.
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end i did this settings

```
$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.[DEVICE].arp_announce=1
$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.[DEVICE].arp_ignore=2
$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.[DEVICE].rp_filter=0
$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.[DEVICE].arp_filter=0
```

i got from
http://jefflane.org/v2/technology/multiple-nics-on-the-same-subnet-avoiding-arp-flux/

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the default configuration for the `arp_filter` option in the network stack. The possible values are documented in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt:

> arp_filter - BOOLEAN
>
> 1 - Allows you to have multiple network interfaces on the same
>       subnet, and have the ARPs for each interface be answered
>       based on whether or not the kernel would route a packet from
>       the ARP'd IP out that interface (therefore you must use source
>       based routing for this to work). In other words it allows control
>       of which cards (usually 1) will respond to an arp request.
>
> 0 - (default) The kernel can respond to arp requests with addresses
>       from other interfaces. This may seem wrong but it usually makes
>       sense, because it increases the chance of successful communication.
>       IP addresses are owned by the complete host on Linux, not by
>       particular interfaces. Only for more complex setups like load-
>       balancing, does this behaviour cause problems.
>
> arp_filter for the interface will be enabled if at least one of
>       conf/{all,interface}/arp_filter is set to TRUE,
>       it will be disabled otherwise

Also `arp_ignore` is relevant here:

> arp_ignore - INTEGER
>       Define different modes for sending replies in response to
>       received ARP requests that resolve local target IP addresses:
>
> 0 - (default): reply for any local target IP address, configured
>       on any interface
>
> 1 - reply only if the target IP address is local address
>       configured on the incoming interface
>
> 2 - reply only if the target IP address is local address
>       configured on the incoming interface and both with the
>       sender's IP address are part from same subnet on this interface

So, after setting `arp_filter` to 1 and `arp_ignore` to 2, you should get the behavior you want.

Comment: Hi Thanks but with those settings sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ens3f1.arp_ignore=2 and sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ens3f1.arp_filter=1 on both devices i get in the arp INCOMPLETE and then FAILED