# ARP responses from host with several interfaces

Tags: debian, tcpip, arp

I have a (experimental) setup where a host `myhost.mydomain` has three network interfaces all connected to the same VLAN as its default gateway `mygateway.mydonain`. The setup looks as follows:

```
interface MAC               IP address
--------- ----------------- ---------------
eth0      aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa myhost.mydomain
eth1      bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb 192.168.0.7
eth2      cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc 192.168.1.7
```

What I observe is that approx. every [4 hours](https://notesbytom.wordpress.com/2015/03/26/arp-timeout-in-cisco-ios/) an ARP request arrives from the default gateway and ARP responses are sent out on all three interfaces. The ARP request (according to `tcpdump`) that is picked up on all three interfaces reads:

```
who-has myhost.mydomain tell mygateway.mydomain
```

The ARP responses read:

```
myhost.mydomain is aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa # on eth0
myhost.mydomain is bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb # on eth1
myhost.mydomain is cc:cc:cc:cc:cc:cc # on eth2
```

Is this how it should be in such a setup? I am a bit surprised because `myhost.mydomain` apparently "is" only `aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa`, since that address is bound to `eth0`. I also see that after these responses the default gateway sends further TCP traffic on `eth2`(instead of `eth0`), which causes other complications.

I am aware that the problem could  propably be solved by `arptables` or by connecting the host's interfaces to different networks, but I'd also like to understand this specific situation before moving on. The host runs Debian 8.9.

**UPDATE** Looks like I have encountered [ARP](https://openvz.org/Multiple_network_interfaces_and_ARP_flux) [flux](http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-arp.html) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a case of ARP flux. The following description applies:

> A peculiar feature of Linux is its willingness to respond to ARP
>   requests for any IP bound to any interface. This can lead to ARP flux,
>   a situation where a given IP is sometimes accessed on one MAC address
>   and sometimes another. ([here](http://linux-ip.net/html/adv-multi-ethernet.html))

The same source suggests this remedy:

> One method for preventing ARP flux involves the use of
>   `net/ipv4/conf/$DEV/arp_filter`. In short, the use of `arp_filter` causes
>   the recipient (in the case below, real-server) to perform a route
>   lookup to determine the interface through which to send the reply,
>   instead of the default behaviour (shown above), replying from all
>   Ethernet interfaces which receive the request. ([here](http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-arp.html#ex-ether-arp-flux-arpfilter))

In order to arrive at a solution that can persist across reboots of `myhost.mydomain` I have chosen the following recipe:

```
echo "net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 1" > /etc/sysctl.d/arp_filter.conf
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/arp_filter.conf
```

I've meanwhile also noted that this type of situation was the subject of [another](https://serverfault.com/questions/872316/wierd-arp-issue-with-2-interafces-sharing-same-subnet) recent question in this forum.